# Popping an item off the top of a circular array contained in a quack (queue/stack)

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, queue

I'm currently trying to write a program that implements a **quack** (queue/stack). In each instance of quack I have a pointer to a character array 'items.' I've already written my `pushBack` and `pushFront` functions, but I went to write my `popFront` and `popBack` functions and realized that I don't know how to dereference an element from an array in this instance.

My teacher provided me with a text file of what the output of the program is supposed to look like, and it needs to look exactly the same as his. In his output file, when the character is popped off of the front or the back of the array, it remains in that place in memory, it just is no longer being used by the array. Because of this, I can't just set an index position back to what it was originally initialized to when I pop it off the front or back of the array. That character needs to stay there, so when I run the code it still shows up even if it's been popped off of the array, until something is pushed onto the array that overwrites it (the capacity of the array is static).

**Note**: my program is creating and writing to a separate text file which shows the array elements from the current front of the array to the back, rather than from *items[0]* to *items[capacity-1]*, and that file does not print the character once it's been popped off of the array.

I have an int variable called *front* which contains the current front index position of the array, and an int variable called *back* which has the index position of the back of the array. When trying to write my `popFront` function, I tried doing something like

```
delete[] &items[front];
```

and that didn't work, and neither did

```
delete[front] items;
```

to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. I have no idea of what syntax I need to use to make this work. I'll provide you with some more of my code here so you can see for yourself:

*Quack* constructor: (and yes, I have to initialize the elements in the array to '-' because
that's how they need to look when they haven't yet been assigned a letter in the output file). Also, implementation is provided for `growBy` which enlarges the array, if I wanted to do a more difficult version of this assignment and make the array dynamic, but I don't have time to do that one so you can just ignore `growBy`.

```
Quack::Quack(int capacity, int growBy) :
    capacity(capacity),
    growBy(growBy),
    nItems(0),
    items(new char[capacity]),
    front(NULL),
    back(NULL)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        items[i] = '-';
    }
}
```

Here is my *Quack* class: (I'm leaving out the `printArray` function inside class Quack because it's long and irrelevant)

```
class Quack
{
public:

    Quack(int capacity, int growBy = 0);
    // capacity: # of slots in array
    // growBy:   # of slots to add to array when it grows, 0 means "don't grow"

    ~Quack(void);
    bool pushFront(const char ch);      // push an item onto the front
    bool pushBack(const char ch);       // push an item onto the back
    bool popFront(char& ch);            // pop an item off the front
    bool popBack(char& ch);             // pop an item off the back
    void rotate(int r);                 // "rotate" the stored items (see note below)
    void reverse(void);                 // reverse the order of the stored items
    int itemCount(void);                // return the current number of stored items

private:
    char    *items;                     // pointer to storage for circular array,
                                            // each item in the array is a char
                                        // items is an array with 

    int     nItems;                     // # of items currently stored in array
    int     capacity;
    int     growBy;                     // # of slots in array
    int     front;
    int     back;

public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Quack *q);
};
```

And finally, here is what I'm doing with `popFront` (you can see where the element dereferencing needs to go; the rest is just where I'm changing front to be correct after the item is popped). `itemCount()` is a function that does nothing but return *nItems*, which is the number of items in the list, something I'm also keeping track of.

```
bool Quack::popFront(char& ch)
{
    // if list is empty, can't pop
    if (itemCount() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // pop front item

    /* here is where I don't know what to do, stackoverflow */

    // increment front and nItems
    if (front < (capacity - 2))
    {
        front++;
        nItems--;
        return false;
    }
    else if (front == (capacity - 1))
    {
        front = 0;
        nItems--;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the proper output for the program in VS, so you can see what it should be doing:

(popFront pops item off front of list, popBack pops item off back of list,
pushFront adds item to front of list, pushBack adds item to back of list)

```
pushFront(a)       [ a - - - - - - ]
pushFront(b)       [ a - - - - - b ]
pushFront(c)       [ a - - - - c b ]
pushFront(d)       [ a - - - d c b ]
pushBack(z)        [ a z - - d c b ]
pushFront(e)       [ a z - e d c b ]
popFront -> e      [ a z - e d c b ]
popFront -> d      [ a z - e d c b ]
pushBack(f)        [ a z f e d c b ]
pushBack(g)        [ a z f g d c b ]
rotate(2)          [ a z f g c b b ]
rotate(-3)         [ a z f g g c b ]
reverse            [ b c g g f z a ]
pushFront(y)       [ b c g y f z a ]
rotate(3)          [ b c g y f z a ]
rotate(-4)         [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> c       [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> b       [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> a       [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> z       [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> f       [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> y       [ b c g y f z a ]
popBack -> g       [ b c g y f z a ]
```

One more note: the reason I'm not throwing any exceptions is because I'm not including any queue implementation in this. The only libs I have are fstream, iostream, ostream and iomanip (and I can't to my knowledge include any others as per the requirements of the assignment).

There is no such reserved term as quack or quackException, it would seem, so in cases where I would throw queueException, I just return false (I assume this is why the functions are of type bool, I can't think of any other reason: we were provided with the function prototypes, just none of the function definitions).

Thank you very much for your time, oh wise ones!

Comment: Sorry but tl;dr cabbages notwithstanding

Comment: `delete[]` is not appropriate for a single element of your array. You need to *shuffle* all the superseding elements back one place to eliminate the element you are deleting and change the top marker accordingly.

Comment: Is a "quack" the same as a [_deque_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue), dequeue, or double-ended queue?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable, `items`, is an array. You can either `delete` the entire array:

```
delete [] items;
```

Or not `delete` any of it, you can't piecewise delete an element.

Comment: There must be some way to do this though? This assignment has been used in cs courses for years

Comment: You shouldn't need to reallocate an array. That's overkill. You just need to keep track of where the "front" and "back" are.

Comment: "when the character is popped off of the front or the back of the array, it remains in that place in memory," -- you shouldn't be deleting the array in push or pop, just modifying the logical ends of the array like @Barry said.

Answer (score -1):

`ch` is passed by reference `&`, which means if you assign a value to it, then that value is assigned to the variable which was passed into the function. Without the `&`, the value passed as a parameter would be copied into `ch` and if you changed `ch` no effect would happen to the original parameter.

Assigning to a reference is similar to assigning to a normal variable. A reference points to the same data as another variable in memory, but it's not a pointer. A reference can only be "pointed" to another variable once, but a pointer can be pointed multiple times.

Here's an example:

```
// A silly example, which doubles the variable passed in
void doubleValue( int& i ) {
    i = i * 2;
}

// Sample use:
int j = 2;
doubleValue( j ); // j is now 4
doubleValue( j ); // j is now 8
```

So if you need to return the popped value in `ch` you could use an array access, just like you normally would to get a value out of the array.

```
char sample = items[front];
```